# Unity build report is missing item in size calculation

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, build, report

I am building a project for both iOS and Android using Unity.

While making file size adjustments I discovered the Build Report appears to be missing info - the numbers shown don't add up to 100%

Here are the reports as well as the actual numbers the reports add up to.

Anyone have thoughts?

***iOS***

Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category:

Textures      160.7 mb   17.8%

Meshes        33.1 mb    3.7%

Animations    7.5 mb     0.8%

Sounds        7.1 mb     0.8%

Shaders       19.7 mb    2.2%

Other Assets  77.1 mb    8.6%

Levels        3.6 mb     0.4%

Scripts       1.2 mb     0.1%

Included DLLs 4.1 mb     0.5%

File headers  1.4 mb     0.2%

Complete size 900.4 mb   100.0%

**actual:       315.5mb              35.10%**

***Android***

Build Report

Uncompressed usage by category:

Textures      485.1 mb   52.0%

Meshes        33.1 mb    3.5%

Animations    7.5 mb     0.8%

Sounds        7.1 mb     0.8%

Shaders       13.5 mb    1.4%

Other Assets  77.1 mb    8.3%

Levels        1.5 mb     0.2%

Scripts       1.2 mb     0.1%

Included DLLs 4.1 mb     0.4%

File headers  1.4 mb     0.1%

Complete size 933.5 mb   100.0%

**actual:   631.6mb             67.60%**

Comment: By the way, Android build size is 309MB, iOS is 215MB currently. Which is why I'm trying to track down places to optimize.

Unity ver 2017.3.1

Comment: Did eve figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the space is made up by the Unity engine itself.

([Source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1339557/complete-size-calculation-does-not-match.html))

Comment: Good guess. But that should be taken into account - and even if not that should be less then 25MB as an empty project project is smaller then that (somewhere between 14 and 20 I seem to recall) so that would "seem" to be the size of Unity in the project.

Though perhaps I am just over thinking it.

Comment: Unity can strip out Engine code that you're not using. So the empty project will have less engine code than your project. This is a build report tool from unity that will do a more in depth analysis. You need to make a build in unity editor, and then this tool will grab a report for you:
http://files.unity3d.com/build-report/